# Passing a function through a list of dataframes - create and give name the objects

Tags: r, function, lapply, purrr

I am looking to automate processes. In that process, I have a dataframe which can be splitted by a factor variable of 3 levels = 3 dataframes (which I will post another question to split cleanly)
What I want to do is pivot_wider across the list of dataframes created after being splitted the original dataframe with 2 goals

1. Create objects to **remain in the Global environment**
2. **Name** them, if it's possible inside the function (OO1, NUTS2, LFD3 for each df)

The code I'm running:

```
f1 <- function(z, id, grup_int, gen, Ct) {
  
 z %>%   
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, grup_int),
              names_from = gen, 
              values_from = Ct) %>%     # I would like to include here setNames for each df
     ungroup() %>% as.data.frame() 

 
}

# Then execute the function with lapply or map - is there any function easier to fix the objects and name them. I don't understand de quotation inside the functions and its variations

lapply(z1, f1)

map(z, f1)
```

Thanks

The data example containing 3 groups that I configured in a list to iterate across. Seems that I am double working splitting the original dataframe (I am not showing it) to after create a list to lapply

```
g1 <- structure(list(id = c(110104019, 120715032, 120715020, 50203029, 
70111022, 140102087, 120715020, 120715033, 140102088, 110113007, 
120715029, 111201026, 110110005, 120715026, 110104028, 140103029, 
110110005, 50527001, 111201026, 130108008), sexo = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), grup_int = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gen = c("pcsk9", 
"abca1", "s18", "il10", "il8ra", "ccl3", "il10", "s18", "nr1h2", 
"cyp27a1", "lag3", "ppard", "lag3", "ptgs1", "nr1h3", "abcg1", 
"cyp27a1", "scarb1", "vcam1", "mcp1"), time = c("1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "3"), Ct = c(NA, 17.781, 10.964, 24.152, 16.463, 
22.747, 23.815, 10.809, 19.229, 18.642, 18.803, 16.583, 21.288, 
16.209, 21.11, 19.298, 17.278, 20.491, 23.792, 23.226), dCt = c(NA, 
5.907, -1.151, 12.796, 3.965, 10.522, 11.7, -1.544, 5.867, 5.97, 
7.252, 5.122, 9.234, 5.412, 9.244, 7.361, 5.224, 8.201, 12.331, 
11.859), RQ = c(NA, 2.356, 0.936, 1.244, 0.464, 1.28, 1.537, 
1.256, 0.486, 1.159, 2.176, 1.244, 1.462, 1.486, 1.344, 0.662, 
1.865, 1.376, 2.358, 1.035)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

g2<- structure(list(id = structure(c(60901033, 60901033, 130106037, 
130102014, 140103027, 110113008, 60901024, 60901033, 110113008, 
130102012, 130106038, 50109026, 70111021, 110104017, 70710002, 
130105045, 110104030, 110104027, 140102092, 110113008), format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    sexo = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
    "1", "9"), label = "INCLUSIÓN: Sexo del participante", class = "factor"), 
    grup_int = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", class = "factor"), 
    gen = c("vcam1", "adrb2", "il23a", "ptgs1", "il23a", "rxra", 
    "ldlr", "mcp1", "ldlr", "il23a", "il8rb", "il8ra", "cd86", 
    "ido", "nampt", "lag3", "tnf", "il23a", "cd36", "cyp27a1"
    ), time = c("1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3"), Ct = c(25.306, 
    15.767, 21.98, 17.683, 21.537, 14.609, 18.772, 24.157, 19.817, 
    21.601, 14.99, 15.876, 16.786, 20.806, 11.702, 19.709, 19.659, 
    22.512, 15.825, 18.518)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


g3 <- structure(list(id = c(130106034, 60901027, 60901035, 130106034, 
50203013, 50430001, 50109025, 50203012, 50203006, 60901027, 130106034, 
50203019, 50203014, 120715012, 50109019, 140103019, 140102090, 
140103019, 110104023, 60901031), sexo = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), grup_int = c(3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), gen = c("nr1h2", 
"cd86", "cd86", "adrb2", "il8ra", "ldlr", "mcp1", "chuk", "olr1", 
"nampt", "s1pr3", "ido", "lrp1", "cxcl2", "ptgs2", "cxcl2", "ppard", 
"gapd", "ptgs1", "pcsk9"), time = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"3", "1"), Ct = c(18.987, 18.701, 17.983, 17.064, 14.62, 19.71, 
24.713, 17.419, 25.328, 12.745, 21.264, 19.5, 17.102, 22.794, 
18.162, 23.335, 17.332, 15.329, 17.895, NA), dCt = c(5.995, 6.199, 
5.644, 4.072, 3.298, 6.907, 12.762, 5.607, 12.525, 0.243, 8.272, 
7.451, 5.007, 11.107, 5.3, 11.513, 3.353, 4.113, 5.42, NA), RQ = c(0.858, 
1.931, 1.235, 0.885, 1.013, 1.52, 1.05, 1.263, 1.538, 0.822, 
0.122, 1.209, 2.202, 1.321, 1.277, 2.002, 4.713, 1.198, 6.309, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

g1 <- as.data.frame(g1)
g2 <- as.data.frame(g2)
g3 <- as.data.frame(g3)

z <- list(g1, g2, g3)
```

The orig_df, the ddCt variable could be used as Ct in the previous (continuous and quantitative variable)

```
orig_df <- structure(list(id = c(50203012, 110113005, 120715025, 110113007, 
110104027, 50203012, 70204055, 140103020, 60901027, 60901020, 
130102014, 50203032, 60901028, 120715033, 110113008, 50203015, 
140101097, 120715021, 140102088, 70802012), grup_int = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", class = "factor"), 
    gen = c("rxra", "ifng", "cd68", "rxra", "cav1", "il10", "il8ra", 
    "nr1h3", "gapdh", "tnf", "il1b", "mcp1", "ptgs2", "nr1h2", 
    "nr1h2", "pcsk9", "s18", "tnf", "ptgs2", "cd86"), ddCt = c(0.212, 
    0.56, 0.299, 0.69, -2.75, -0.746, -0.064, 0.721, 0, 0.677, 
    0.021, -0.248, 0.075, -0.421, -0.008, NA, 0.19, -0.481, -0.84, 
    0.093)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Having functions that inject values into the global environment is not a good practice. Everything is so much easier if you simply return a named list from your function. Then if it is absolutely necessary to turn those into separate variables, then you can use `list2env` to make that happen. But it's almost always much easier to work with data in a list.

Comment: 1st) In this case it's easier for me to work with dfs. How could it be done? And 2nd) how would you execute your recommendation with the returned list?